# MS VS 2010 - Web one click publish toolbar is disabled when code file is viewed

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I use VS 2010 and the deploy function and to get quick access to the functionality I showed Web One Click Publish toolbar. But the toolbar is only activated when I open Web.config files or when I open Properties of a web project. When I open C# code file that toolbar is disabled. I think the functionality should be enabled independently like for example functionality Build project.

Is it something wrong in my VS installation or configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've just found that it is disabled when code file being viewed (active) does not belong to Web project (but to other one instead that cannot be published).